# how to make a pause menu for iphone game?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I was wondering which method is the easiest or "smartest" way of making a pause menu for games?

I don´t have that much experience with creating game pause menus so I´ve tried 2 methods that I came up with by my own. Both or in code beneath this text.

The first method I tried was to put a black almost transparent filter on top of the game, that I paused. I was successful with pausing everything except the touches made underneath the filter on my uiimages. I thought that putting a new uiimage on top of the current one would disable the touches made on the uiimages underneath it. I tried as well with touchenabled = NO but still nothing.

```
-(IBAction)pause{

NSLog(@"pause");

[countdowntimer invalidate];

[self.rubin1 stopAnimating];
[self.rubin2 stopAnimating];  
[self.rubin3 stopAnimating];

Pause.enabled = NO;
music1.enabled = NO;
music2.enabled = NO;
sfx1.enabled = NO;
sfx2.enabled = NO;

//PauseMenu background
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed: @"filter2.png"];
pausefilter = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1] autorelease];
CGRect newFrame1 = pausefilter.frame; 
newFrame1 = CGRectMake(0,0, image1.size.width, image1.size.height);
pausefilter.frame = newFrame1; 

[self.view addSubview:pausefilter];

[image1 release];

//Resume to Game
button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(90, 146, 80, 18);
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RESUME.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(resume) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[ self.view addSubview: button1 ];

//End Game
button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(260, 140, 180, 30);
[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EndGame.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(end) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[ self.view addSubview: button2 ];

[sharedSoundManager pausePlayingMusic];
```

}

The second method I tried was to go back (switch view) to the options on the main menu to use the settings from there instead but I wasn´t able to resume back to where I paused the game. Instead the game restarted from the beginning.

```
-(IBAction)pause{

NSLog(@"pause");

[countdowntimer invalidate];

[self.rubin1 stopAnimating];
[self.rubin2 stopAnimating];  
[self.rubin3 stopAnimating];

Pause.enabled = NO;
music1.enabled = NO;
music2.enabled = NO;
sfx1.enabled = NO;
sfx2.enabled = NO;

menureturn = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle: nil];
menureturn.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:menureturn animated: YES];

self.menureturn.Start.hidden = YES;
self.menureturn.option.hidden = YES;
self.menureturn.OptionsHeadtitle.hidden = NO;
self.menureturn.HowToPlayHeadtitle.hidden = YES;
self.menureturn.howtoplay.hidden = YES;
self.menureturn.filter.hidden = NO;
self.menureturn.music1.hidden = NO;
self.menureturn.music2.hidden = YES;
self.menureturn.SFXimage.hidden = NO; 
self.menureturn.Musicimage.hidden = NO; 
self.menureturn.sfx1.hidden = NO;
self.menureturn.sfx2.hidden = YES;
self.menureturn.credits.hidden = YES;
self.menureturn.back.hidden = YES;
self.menureturn.creditsinfo.hidden = YES;
self.menureturn.resume.hidden = NO;
self.menureturn.endgame.hidden = NO;

[sharedSoundManager pausePlayingMusic];
```

}

Is there a third option of how to make a god pause menu or just redo one of the two I already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a BOOL variable like

> BOOL isGamePaused

Now when you are playing game i.e running not paused assign

> isGamePaused = NO;

While you pause

> isGamePaused = YES;

Now while playing animation or something like that you can use condition like

> if(!isGamePaused) { ProceedAnimation;}

Hope this helps

Comment: will this method disable the touches? :)

Comment: in touches you can also check the similar concept. if you are doing any action in touch than check the same condition and ignore if game is paused.

Comment: do you mean in the touches methods?

Comment: I think that's what he means. Just don't check the events if game is paused

Comment: hope to be able to return the help someday ;)

Comment: I am really happy that it worked for you. And of course everybody will need some help from others so when my turn comes it may be you can help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to disable any event is to create a new element in your pause menu which will be the first responder and catches all events. So nothing can arrive to your game's interface ;)

Comment: I thought I did that with adding the filter and the two buttons to the view :)

Comment: yes, but you must tell your filter to catch any event it can ;) So reimplement the corresponding functions from UIResponder so they are not propagated to the first responding object. Note that Jennis' way to do it isn't bad even if you have to cope with a simili-global variable

Comment: sorry for sounding extremely like a noob but which uiresponder? Don´t recall using a uiresponder in the code for this (if that´s the case then... oops! :) ). I agree, Jennis´way isn´t bad either. it´s good to have several solutions though. ;)

Comment: Ow, don't worry^^ Just forget to say that an UIView is an UIResponder, as any object that can catch an event ;)

Comment: hehe... OK. I should have connected the dots better, I guess.  I thought though that touchesenabled = NO whould do that exact thing (correct me if I´m wrong)

Comment: Hmm, I don't really remember, but there's no such method for UIResponder... I just prefer not saying something wrong

Comment: no worries. you gave me lots of stuff to try out, both of you. thanks. i´ll try both of your methods and let you know how it turned out. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I tried both of your ideas but I went with Jennis´way. :D

Comment: hope to be able to return the help someday ;)